# Right/left clicks on touchpad not turning off when in tablet mode

Tags: drivers, 22.04, touchpad, wayland, 22.10

When I fold my Thinkpad Yoga's screen, my laptop enters tablet mode and disables keyboard and mouse movement.  However, it doesn't disable pressing the right or left click buttons for the touchpad.

Is it possible to disable right/left click when my laptop enters tablet mode?

This problem has been happening since as long as I've used Ubuntu on my laptop, when Ubuntu was at version 21.10

My specifications:

[image: about page]

Comment: What release are you asking about? as you mention three. Are you using Ubuntu 21.10? (which is EOL), Ubuntu 22.04? or Ubuntu 22.10?  (*drivers* are kernel modules; thus are built for a release & thus release details matter!)   Your picture highlights *kinetic* or 22.10, but your question text & tags do not.

Comment: @guiverc
I am currently on Ubuntu 22.10, but this was also happening on 22.04 and I am happy to revert to ubuntu 22.04 if there's a fix/something to try on Ubuntu 22.04